# Query for Last Fees Date in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am beginner in sql server.i have two table, TestshriMaster and Testshrifees. i need one record which have student last paid fees details. i wrote one query ,but is there any simple way to do this. help appreciated.3 user in table which are "nixon","shri","nixon".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports Standard SQL's *Windowed Aggregate Functions*, in your case you need a [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186734%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
select ... 
from TestshriMaster as sm
 (
   select *, 
      ROW_NUMBER()                         -- apply a ranking 
      OVER (PARTITION BY studentid         -- for each student
            ORDER BY feesdate DESC ) AS rn -- based on descending dates
   from Testshrifees
 ) as sf
on sm.studentid = sf.stundentid
where sf.rn = 1                            -- return only the latest row
```